# Method not being called when button is pressed?

Tags: c#, replace, blazor, webassembly

I am just trying to create a simple application that when a button is pressed, it will take a piece of text and replace a certain string with another string. For some reason when my "Replace" button is pressed, it is not giving me my new string.

I have tried various bind options, but having some troubles understanding why this is not working. I must be missing a simple piece but cannot see it.

Also is there a way to use a built in clipboard feature to be able to copy the text after it has been "filtered"? I saw a way of doing it with JS but I want to use strictly c#.

Here is my code:

agenthelper.razor

```
@page "/agent-helper"

<div class="input-container">
    <label for="originalString">Input string</label>
    <div class="input-wrapper">
        <input id="originalString" name="originalString" type="text" @bind="originalString" title="Input string" />
    </div>
</div>

<div class="button-container">
    <button @onclick="ReplaceString" class="button-style button-one">Replace</button>
    <button @onclick="Copy" class="button-style">Copy</button>
</div>

<div class="input-container">
    <label for="modifiedString">Cleaned string</label>
    <div class="input-wrapper">
        @* <input id="modifiedString" name="modifiedString" type="text" value="@modifiedString" readonly /> *@
        <input id="modifiedString" name="modifiedString" type="text" @bind="modifiedString" readonly />
    </div>
</div>

@code {
    private string originalString;
    private string modifiedString;

    private void ReplaceString()
    {
        @* modifiedString = originalString.Replace("$env:SystemDrive\\", "D:\\"); *@
        modifiedString = originalString.Replace("hello test", "test worked");
        StateHasChanged();
    }


    private async Task Copy()
    {

    }
}
```

App.razor

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <base href="/" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="bootstrap/bootstrap.min.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="app.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="Team.Helpers.styles.css" />
    <link rel="icon" type="image/png" href="favicon.png" />
    <HeadOutlet />
</head>

<body>
    <Routes />
    <script src="_framework/blazor.web.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

Tried using various bindings

Comment: Just to confirm: You are using Blazor WebAssembly <= .NET 7 or Interactive WebAssembly  render mode on .NET 8 and have configured your application accordingly? On .NET 8 the default ist static server-side rendering, so you'd have to configure it manually.

Comment: Sorry I should have specified. Its Interactive WebAssembly render mode on .NET 8. I created the project using the "Auto" configuration. So i'm assuming there is an issue with that? @Mushroomator

Comment: Add your `App.razor` to your question.  My first guess is you chose the Auto and Per Page/Component options and have no interactivity set.  You're playing with a static page.

Comment: I just edited and added it to the original post. So that means just as it sounds, nothing can interactive with that current page? @MrCakaShaunCurtis

Answer (score 0):

The issue probably is that you do not have the *Interactive Webassembly* render mode setup properly.

First you need to enable the support by registering the required services with DI.

```cs
// Register services
builder.Services.AddRazorComponents()
    .AddInteractiveWebAssemblyComponents();

// Use Interactive WebAsssembly
app.MapRazorComponents<App>()
    .AddInteractiveWebAssemblyRenderMode();
```

Then depending on what you want to to define the render mode used on the

- entire app
- page
- component
  level.

To do it on the page level you should add the following on the top of your page:

```
@rendermode InteractiveWebAssembly
```

When you have that properly setup, it should work. To get an better understanding of why that is necessary and what happens under the covers I would recommonend this YouTube video from .NET Conf 2023: [Full stack web UI with Blazor in .NET 8 | .NET Conf 2023](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=YwZdtLEtROA).

All these rather complex topics of what is rendered when and where is unfortunately to much to get into here in detail, but the video covers the essentials and there are plenty more resources out there.

For more details please see the [Micorsoft Docs - ASP.NET Core Blazor render modes](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/components/render-modes?view=aspnetcore-8.0).

Comment: Okay that is probably the issue then, thanks so much for the explanation and the help. I was banging my head against the wall wondering why it wasn't working. I'll be sure to watch the video and read that documentation and try those fixes. Cheers :)

Comment: I did try adding all of these lines you said to but when I run my project, it just loads a blank page and in the developer console I get a 500 error saying "failed to load resource". I did read the documentation and saw that this should be good enough if I wanna render a single page so still a bit confused. My page is in the client folder of the project as well

Answer (score 0):

If you created the project using Auto mode,
You either need to modify App as follows for Global Interactivity.

```cs
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <base href="/" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="bootstrap/bootstrap.min.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="app.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="Team.Helpers.styles.css" />
    <link rel="icon" type="image/png" href="favicon.png" />
    <HeadOutlet  @rendermode="InteractiveAuto" />
</head>

<body>
    <Routes @rendermode="InteractiveAuto" />
    <script src="_framework/blazor.web.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

Or set Interactivity on every page like this:

```cs
@page "/agent-helper"
@rendermode InteractiveAuto

<div class="input-container">
    <label for="originalString">Input string</label>
    <div class="input-wrapper">
        <input id="originalString" name="originalString" type="text" @bind="originalString" title="Input string" />
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: So after reading documentation, this will add the rendermode over the entire application if i'm correct? But I thought when making the project with automode, that WebAssembly was already made with the .Client folder or am i missing something.

Comment: See my updated answer.  Auto looks wonderful at first sight.  It's a honeypot for first timers.  However, building a real application in Auto per page mode is both complex and challenging.  You can read a personal commentary by me on the topic here.  https://shauncurtis.github.io/Posts/Mongrel-Blazor.html

Comment: Great write-up, it helped me visualize things a bit better. Auto is still a bit confusing so i'll have to read up more on that. I actually just kept the initial configuration of the application as auto but decided to render the page in InteractiveServer and it is working now. Thank you for the help :)